# @Embedded Audit was working with spring boot 1.4 but now not working after upgrade to spring boot 2.1.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-2

```
public interface EAuditable {
    public static interface Update{
        public EUpdateInfo getUpdateInfo();
        public void setUpdateInfo(EUpdateInfo updateInfo);
    }
    public static interface Create{
        public ECreateInfo getCreateInfo();
        public void setCreateInfo(ECreateInfo createInfo);
    }
    public static interface UpdateDate{
        public ZonedDateTime getLastUpdatedOn();
        public void setLastUpdatedOn(ZonedDateTime date);
    }
    public static interface UpdateUser{
        public String getLastUpdatedBy();
        public void setLastUpdatedBy(String user);
    }
    public static interface CreateDate{
        public ZonedDateTime getCreatedOn();
        public void setCreatedOn(ZonedDateTime date);
    }
    public static interface CreateUser{
        public String getCreatedBy();
        public void setCreatedBy(String user);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRACKABLE_ITEM")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ETrackableItem extends AbstractIdTenantPersistable implements EAuditable.Create, EAuditable.Update {

    @Embedded
    private ECreateInfo createInfo;
    @Embedded
    private EUpdateInfo updateInfo;
}

@MappedSuperclass
//JPA: For Eclipse Link, use @AdditionaliCritera instead of @Filter and @FilterDef
@FilterDef(name="multiTenant", parameters=@ParamDef( name="tenant_id", type="string" ) )
@Filter(name="multiTenant", condition=":tenant_id = TENANT_ID")
public abstract class AbstractIdTenantPersistable extends AbstractIdPersistable {

    @Column(name = "TENANT_ID", length = 12)
    protected String tenantId;


    public String getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

    protected AbstractIdTenantPersistable(){}

    protected AbstractIdTenantPersistable(UUID id) {
        super(id);
    }

    protected AbstractIdTenantPersistable(UUID id, String tenantId) {
        super(id);
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

}

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(value = { PersistableEntityListener.class })
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonUserType.class)
public abstract class AbstractPersistable {
    public enum ConstraintType{UniqueName, Unique, Others};

    /**
     * Returns the constraint name to its type mapping.
     * @param name
     * @return
     */
    public ConstraintType getConstraintType(String name){
        return ConstraintType.Others;
    }
}

public class PersistableEntityListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(AbstractPersistable e) {
        if (e instanceof EAuditable.Create){
            EAuditable.Create create = (EAuditable.Create) e;
            create.setCreateInfo(new ECreateInfo(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")), getUserName()));
        }
        if (e instanceof EAuditable.CreateDate){
            EAuditable.CreateDate createDate = (EAuditable.CreateDate) e;
            createDate.setCreatedOn(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
        }
        if (e instanceof EAuditable.CreateUser){
            EAuditable.CreateUser createUser = (EAuditable.CreateUser) e;
            createUser.setCreatedBy(getUserName());
        }
        if (e instanceof AbstractIdTenantPersistable){
            ((AbstractIdTenantPersistable)e).setTenantId(getTenantId());
        }
        preUpdate(e);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(AbstractPersistable e) {
        if (e instanceof EAuditable.Update){
            EAuditable.Update update = (EAuditable.Update) e;
            update.setUpdateInfo(new EUpdateInfo(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")), getUserName()));
        }
        if (e instanceof EAuditable.UpdateDate){
            EAuditable.UpdateDate updateDate = (EAuditable.UpdateDate) e;
            updateDate.setLastUpdatedOn(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
        }
        if (e instanceof EAuditable.UpdateUser){
            EAuditable.UpdateUser updateUser = (EAuditable.UpdateUser) e;
            updateUser.setLastUpdatedBy(getUserName());
        }
    }

    private String getUserName() {
        //checkContext();
        if (isUserSet()){
            return ContextHolder.get().getAuthenticatedContext().getUserName();
        }
        return "-";
    }

    private String getTenantId() {
        //checkContext();
        if (isTenantSet()){
            return ContextHolder.get().getAuthenticatedContext().getTenantId();
        }
        return "-";
    }

    private boolean isUserSet(){
        return ContextHolder.get() != null &&
                ContextHolder.get().getAuthenticatedContext() != null &&
                ContextHolder.get().getAuthenticatedContext().getUserName() != null;
    }

    private boolean isTenantSet(){
        return ContextHolder.get() != null &&
                ContextHolder.get().getAuthenticatedContext() != null &&
                ContextHolder.get().getAuthenticatedContext().getTenantId() != null;
    }

    private boolean isContextSet(){
        return isUserSet() && isTenantSet();
    }

    private void checkContext(){
        BeanHolder.asserts().isTrue(
                isContextSet(),`enter code here`
                DomainException.class, "DOMAIN.CONTEXT_NOT_SET");
    }
}
```

Below the code which was working fine for auto populate the audit info with the spring-data-jpa used with spring boot 1.4.x but it is not working when we upgraded to spring boot 2.1.x
Can any one please help if we have different way of handing for the same.
I need to follow this kind of @Embedded way of doing as here we are doing it by composition except inheritance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the error you are getting? stack trace will help